# Extention for scrolling down in linux terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

I want to scroll down in pages in terminal that are not command running area like in **man page** or **set | less** page.

I have discovered that through pressing **fn** *key*, we can scroll down fast and the right and left arrows take you to the bottom or start respectively. Is there some **code to program an extention** via which we can scroll down smoothly like a scroller. It may allow a scroller to appear or so upon which mouse could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many terminal emulators show a scroll bar and allow you to see the "history" of what I think you call the "command running area". Your shell and many commands you can run from a shell just print to the terminal in a "linear" fashion, line by line. Your terminal emulator may be set up to remember lines that went off-screen, then it lets you scroll to see them.

Scrolling in `less` or `man` (which uses a pager that may be `less`, `more` or `most` anyway) is different. A program like `less` [requests an alternate screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38638/108618). The terminal emulator does not save anything. Scrolling (if any) happens because the program does it by controlling the whole screen.

Note there's a big conceptual difference:

- The former method of scrolling involves your terminal emulator only, but neither the shell nor any program run by the shell is aware what part of the history you're seeing at the moment.
- The latter method involves `less` or a similar program that in general may scroll by rewriting the whole screen again and again. The terminal emulator happily shows these changes, but it's the program that controls what you see.

The terminal emulator may (and does) display a GUI scroll bar. AFAIK there is no standard interface for a program like `less` to request such bar. What a program can do is to display its own bar using characters. Less does not do this, some programs may ([example](https://superuser.com/q/276334/432690)).

The program may or may not react to mouse scroll events. What you described ("I have discovered that …") is a pager reacting to <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>PgDown</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd><sup>1</sup>. Scroll events and these keys are transmitted as [escape sequences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103764/108618) in the same stream that carries what you type.

It seems nowadays [you can make `less` react to mouse scroll](https://superuser.com/q/455212/432690).

If a program does not natively react to mouse scroll, a practical method is to translate scroll events to (series of) arrow keys or so. Your terminal emulator may be able to do it. It may be able to do it *selectively*, depending on the (local) command that runs in the foreground (e.g. it will do the translation only if the command is `less`, `more` or `man`).

It's possible to do the translation between a terminal emulator and a program. `tmux` can do it. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/990887/432690) and [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1319237/432690). The latter contains code for `~/.tmux.conf`, the code captures `WheelUpPane` and sends 3x`Up` etc. In fact I use this or similar code. There are more reasons to use `tmux`, its primary job is multiplexing terminals (creating windows and panes). Selective translation by `tmux` may be better than selective translation by a terminal emulator if you use `ssh`<sup>2</sup>.

Whatever works for you, do not expect scrolling controlled by `less` or a similar program to be totally smooth. Even if the input is smooth (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1635439/432690)) and even if your terminal was able to pass smooth data to the program (and I think it's not able), the program works with a grid of WIDTHxHEIGHT *characters* and there is no way for it to scroll by a fraction of a line. Technically a GUI terminal emulator should be able to scroll pixel-line by pixel-line, at least when it alone is responsible for scrolling (i.e. within what we called the former method); still the terminal emulators I work with always scroll character-line by character-line even then.

I guess translating one "tick" of mouse wheel to several up or down keys (and tolerating choppy updates of the entire screen) is the best you can do. If another answer proves me wrong, all the better.

---

<sup>1</sup> Almost always <kbd>fn</kbd> is handled internally by the keyboard and the OS is unaware, it just gets *different* keystrokes. Apparently with <kbd>fn</kbd> your arrow keys become <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>PgDown</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>.

<sup>2</sup> To clarify: if you run local `less` in the foreground, your local terminal emulator is able to tell it's `less`; but if you run `ssh` locally and then you run `less` *on the server* then your local terminal emulator can only spot `ssh`, it doesn't know what program runs on the server, its behavior cannot depend on the remote program. But if you run `tmux` *on the server* and you run `less` within `tmux` then `tmux` will be able to spot `less` because they both run in the same OS.

Comment: 1. "The terminal emulator may (and does) display a GUI scroll bar. AFAIK there is no standard interface for a program like less to request such bar." – There were discussions among some terminal emulator developers to allow `less` and alike to hook up to the graphical scrollbar. The approach was abandoned. It would need to be two-way communication, scrolling (by regular mens like Up/Down arrows) affecting the scrollbar, and dragging the scrollbar affecting the contents scroll offset. Combined with the inevitable asynchronous delay between the terminal emulator and the application...

Comment: ... These just led to a level of complexity that we didn't feel like it was worth tackling, or could have been done in a nice robust way, without UI flickers.

Comment: 2. Re your footnote 2: Maybe some emulators do this, but I think it would be ugly to check the process tree upon each mouse scroll event. Instead, a feature called "alternate scroll mode" is available in many terminals, it means that if the terminal is on its alternate screen and the app is not interested in mouse events then convert mouse wheel events into up/down keypresses. This works even across ssh.

Comment: 3. "Technically a GUI terminal emulator should be able to scroll pixel-line by pixel-line, at least when it alone is responsible for scrolling" – Yes, it's an existing thing. At least the VTE terminal emulation engine (used by GNOME Terminal and many other frontends) does this.

Comment: @egmont Interesting details you have. The answer is now community wiki. Improve it at will.